# Receiving Control Codes in C Programming

Tags: c, terminal, curses, kindle

I'm writing a terminal program on the Kindle Paperwhite 2. I compile using tcc. I use linux. I want to implement functions such as `gotoxy(x,y)` and the Mouse.
To move the cursor, I need to send control codes. I found I use printf like this:

```
printf("\033[%d;%dH",y,x);
```

The problem is how to receive control codes sent back to me from the terminal.
I'm reading [this document](http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html#Mouse%20Tracking)

I wrote the following code:

```
printf("\033[?9h");//this turns on the mouse in the terminal
while (1)
{
    printf("\n");
    sleep(1);
}
```

Using scanf or getch() doesn't capture anything. 
Now every time I click, I see a code on the screen (like "^[[M 9.").
It's as if the code doesn't get printed unless a newline is printer.
I need to be able to capture the last two characters as decimals which i think is the xy of the screen.
Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: maybe scanf().  It is the input version of printf()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly recommend not dealing with the escape sequences. Use `ncurses`.

Now [keep in mind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) that

> Because the console driver has no way to know
>          the device or type of the mouse, these reports are returned in the
>          console input stream only when the virtual terminal driver receives a
>          mouse update ioctl.